# Batch script to merge files using copy command in numerical order

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

Would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this request.

I need a dynamic batch script which can do the below command for **ANY number of files**:

```
Copy 1.txt + 2.txt + 3.txt + 4.txt newfile.txt
```

The problem is, if I have the following files:

1.txt

2.txt

3.txt

...so on

And I try: `Copy *.txt newfile.txt` It does not sort correctly when merging.

It actually ends up doing this: `Copy 3.txt + 4.txt + 2.txt + 1.txt newfile.txt`

Also, I need it to use the **copy** command and NOT the type command.

I could not find a proper way of doing this as most of the FOR loop examples online use TYPE and that is not suitable for what I'm trying to achieve.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will soon find out that files listed in a batch file will not sort in a numeric order.  Files will come out as 1.txt 10.txt 2.txt, etc..... You will need an additional utility to get the files in the order you want.  I suggest you use Dave Benham's JSORT utility. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595

Comment: @Squashman: You're probably right...

Comment: There is also a SORTN.BAT utility at Dostips.com.  Again you would need to pipe the results of the DIR command to this batch file and then capture the output to build your copy command. http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.SortTextWithNumbers

Comment: Note that a command line like this is limited in its length, 8192 bytes, I think... another thing: are there `.txt` files with leading zeros like `01.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET _cmd=COPY
FOR /F %%G IN ( 'DIR /O:N /B *.txt' ) DO (
    SET _cmd=!_cmd! %%G +
)
SET _cmd=!_cmd:~0,-2! newfile.txt
ECHO !_cmd!
```

The script is "inert" in that it outputs the finished command-line, but doesn't actually issue it. Remove the `ECHO` on the final line to activate it.

Comment: Thanks but this still does not work in the right order. It's still merging in this order:  3.txt  4.txt  2.txt  1.txt

Comment: @binaryfinary: How embarassing, I missed to include the sorting flag... fixed for that matter. However, if your files go up into the 2-digit range, you will see the problems Squashman has already hinted at...

Comment: You are awesome! Works exactly as needed. Thank you!